# How do I get the Public Key from Data Protection API and share it?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, rsa, data-protection

I was reading a fine article on [`Data Protection API`](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3431139/how-to-use-the-data-protection-api-in-aspnet-core.html) here.

With such in mind, I am thinking of encrypting the payload and require the Public Key to be shared among clients. I have the `RSA` type Public key generated from OpenSSL in the form of *.pem. Client's with the use of my public key will encrypt their request and send it to us using an `HTTPS` `GET/POST`. For such, I need to extract the Public key from Data Protection API and ironically no article mentions how to get it.

I also note that there is an expiry tag applied to keys, and how Data-protection-API handle keys that are expired? Can the client request another?

Comment: Usually you feed a seed (a string) to into the encryption code to get the key.  Then share the string.

Comment: @jdweng Can you elaborate a little bit further, please

Comment: I don't understand what your public key has to do with the data protection API. Did you mean private key? Please clarify.

Comment: The link shows a helper method with a string key.  The same key need to be used by client and server.  I can't tell from code if the string key is the seed or the actual key.  RSA has a Private Key and a public key.  The private key is change on a regular basis like once a year and is in a certificate.  The public key is sent with each message and is different for each message.  You need both the public and private key to decrypt a message.  TLS is used before any HTTP Request is sent and is a negotiation between client and server to use same certificate and same encryption algorithm.